# Troubles reading from Internet Live Audio Stream via HTTP in Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-streaming

I am experimenting some troubles while developing a Windows phone 8.1 application in C#  which attempts to read Internet Audio Streams‏ from different radiostream servers.

Among the methods to set the source of the Background Audio Player I have proved with success the method MediaPlayer.SetUriSource,  but unfortunately the media Player experiments missfunctions when playing Audio streams with shoutcast metadata‏.

‎
Especifically the Audio Player eventually stops playing when reading a shoutast stream.‏

‎
For this reason I tried to use the setStreamSource method, by establishing a HTTP conection with the audiostreaming Server and requesting the desired stream to Play, but unfortunately the application can only read the first 64Kbytes of the received audiostream. After that, the thread that manages the stream request dies, without providing errors or debugging Information.

I would like to add that I tried a normal Console Application with a similar code, and it worked fine!

Here some examples of how I implemented the stream request:

```
var HClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await HClient.GetAsync(streamUrl,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
_dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();


HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(streamUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
_dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();


 HttpClient hcb = new HttpClient();
_dataStream = await hcb.GetStreamAsync(streamUrl);


var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, streamUrl);
HttpResponseMessage response = await hcb.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
_dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

The result is in all cases the same: I receive a short chunk of audiostream (about 5-8 seconds) which‏ I can Play and hear, and after some seconds the thread stops. I was able to Count the number of Bytes I was able to read from the stream and it is in all cases 65536.

Comment: Having the same issue .Do you find a solution for it ?